# Automatically display div on mouse hover and hideaway when mouse remove

Tags: jquery, css, html

i have following div html code.

```
<div class="container">

                        <div class="images">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/products/<?php echo $product->image;?>" />

                        </div>

                        <div class="compareme"><h3>Compare Me</h3></div>

</div>
```

And followig CSS and jquery code:

```
.compareme{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:70px;
    left: 110px;
    height: 300px;
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right:30px;

    font-size:12px;


}

$('.product-images').on('mouseover',function(){
        $('.compareme').show();

    });
```

the problem is, when i hover that .image div, the all divs display that compare me message.
What i actually wanted is like when I over over the .image div, that particular .compareme should appear and fade away when i remove mouse from my .image div

So, please help on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, i take it to mean you have more then one .compareme div?

Comment: Yes, it is in for loop displaying lots of products

Comment: gotcha, and you want it to display when you hover over the .images that is its sibling in the HTML?

Comment: Yup, i when i hover over the .image div, it should display .compareme div but in only that container. Other .compareme div should not be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion 1 (javascript):

You will need 'this' keyword ([How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)).

Working example also on https://jsfiddle.net/2dyxydLa/

```js
$('.product-image')
    .on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).parent().next().show();
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).parent().next().hide();
    });
```

```css
.compareme{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:70px;
    left: 110px;
    height: 300px;
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right:30px;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">    
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="product-image" />        
    </div>    
    <div class="compareme"><h1>Compare Me</h1></div>    
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="product-image" />        
    </div>    
    <div class="compareme"><h3>Compare Me</h3></div>    
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="product-image" />        
    </div>    
    <div class="compareme"><h2>Compare Me</h2></div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Suggestion 2 (css):

As suggested by @super-xp you can simply use CSS:

```css
.compareme {
  display:none;
}

.container:hover .compareme {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />

  </div>

  <div class="compareme"><h3>Compare Me</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />

  </div>

  <div class="compareme"><h3>Compare Me</h3></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />

  </div>

  <div class="compareme"><h3>Compare Me</h3></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your may use :hover to do this,for example there are two elements,classname is a and b

> if .a is the ancestor node

```
.a:hover .b {display: block}
```

> if .a is the sibling node just before .b

```
.a:hover + b {display: block}
```

also, your can use css3 transition to make it smooth

Answer (score 0):

Little bit devious, but I think this is a way to do that in pure JavaScript.

```js
div = {
 show: function(elem) {
  document.getElementById(elem).style.display = "block"; 
 }, 
 hide: function(elem) {
  document.getElementById(elem).style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

```css
#list1 {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
 <h4 class="header" onMouseOver="div.show('list1')" onMouseOut="div.hide('list1')"><strong>Support</strong></h4>
  </div>

  <div id="list4">
  <ul>
   <li class="list">Image1</li>
   <li class="list">Image2</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```